# glutExitgamemode callback error

Tags: opengl, fullscreen, glut, fatal-error

I am writing a program to learn how to use opengl and glut in general and i have have problem with glut that i don't really quite understand what is wrong with it.

I can create a glut window and enter full screen mode just fine, but whenever i make a call to glut game mode, it works, but when i exit glut game, the program crashes rather than returning to a small window.
I get the following errors:

2011-12-10 01:09:43.709 ogl[979:903] GLUT Warning: The following is a new check for GLUT 3.0; update your code.

2011-12-10 01:09:43.710 ogl[979:903] GLUT Fatal Error: redisplay needed for window 2, but no display callback.

What am I suppose to do when before calling glut exit game mode to to make the program work right?

This is a snippet of the code:

`switch (key)
    {
  case 27:
    exit(0);
  break;
 case 97:
   glutGameModeString("640x480:32@60");
   glutEnterGameMode();`

break;
    case 99:
      glutLeaveGameMode();
    case 98:
      glutFullScreen();
      break;
    }

This is my code in main:

`int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

  glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
 
 glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
 
 glutCreateWindow("GameMode");`

windows = glutGetWindow();

glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
 
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
  
glutKeyboardFunc(keyhandle);
  
glutMainLoop();
}

Answer (score 0):

> 2011-12-10 01:09:43.710 ogl[979:903] GLUT Fatal Error: redisplay needed for window 2, but no display callback.

This message tells you, that GLUT expects you to give it a display callback function. *glutDisplayFunc* is used for this.

It's impossible to tell, if, or if not this is your problem, because you didn't provided your code.

Comment: i posted up my code in main. the problem is when i exit game mode that the program crashes. i wouldn't have been able to enter game mode and get a full screen if i didn't used glutDisplayFunc, would I?

Comment: i see. i didn't add the display function after glutLeaveGameMode(); i got it to work now thanks